# What is a non-invasive OS-independent test to verify the PostgreSQL system user password is NULL?

Tags: postgresql, command-line, passwords, puppet

This seems like a deceptively easy question to answer, but may not be.

Let's look at a different (easier) case.  How can we verify that the system user password is 'SOMEPASS', assuming that the system user is 'postgres'.

```
su - postgres; env PGPASSWORD=SOMEPASS psql -h localhost -c 'select' > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Invalid password."
fi
```

The -h on psql forces the connection to use TCP instead of a domain socket, which forces a password-based login.  Otherwise the default pg_hba.conf is configured to allow passwordless connections from the system user over domain socket.

What is an analogous version of the test above but which can verify that the system user password is NULL?  The test should return 0 if the system user has a NULL password, and 1 if not.

Additionally, since I am hoping to convert this into generic code for use in puppet across Windows, Solaris, and Linux OS's, the solution should (can not?) make use of helper command-line utilities like sed, awk, perl, etc.

Comment: You mean the operating system user, e.g. the "postgres" user in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` on traditional unix systems? Or are you referring to the `postgres` database superuser?

Comment: The postgres database superuser, not the OS user.  Basically if you do a 'select rolname, rolpassword from pg_authid' you will see the users, and anyone with a NULL password will be blank under that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn any `psql` query into a return value in the shell you have a couple of options:

1. Have `psql` emit a single boolean and test that with `grep -q`;
2. Have `psql` emit zero rows or non-zero rows; or
3. Have your query fail with an `ERROR` in one case, and test `psql`'s return value

Of these I tend to prefer the first, and that's pretty easy with your case:

```
if psql -At -c "select CASE WHEN rolpassword IS NULL THEN 'FAIL' ELSE 'OK' END from pg_authid WHERE rolname = 'postgres';" | grep -q FAIL; then
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!I had started down the path of the #3 idea but hadn't gotten very far.  I like #1 and should be able to use it effectively.  As far as making this OS-independent (e.g. Windows compatible), I think that OS may simply be too limited to make use of solutions like this.  Unless some super Windows savvy person wants to attempt an analogous solution for that platform, I'll consider this question definitively answered.

Comment: @r3cgm you can do a lot with cmd.exe if you're willing to suffer nightmares and potential loss of eyesight. Look into `FOR /F` for example. In this case, `findstr` might do what you want; see `%ERRORLEVEL%`. These days I often just install msys (usually by installing msysgit) and use the unix-like tools, though, it's less painful. Or use MS's PowerShell, which is quite cool once you get your head around it. Or use vbscript ('cscript.exe'). You've got lots of moderately crap options to choose from ;-)